# This localhost:5173 page can’t be found

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9

im getting this error in my vue 3 code : No webpage was found for the web address: **http://localhost:5173/activate-account/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5OGY1ODdlZi0yMjNiLTQ0OTgtODA0Yy1iNjU2OTUzMDE2N2YiLCJqdGkiOiIwODYzM2ExYjFlZTJiNDNkMzRlNGFhMjQyOWI2Mjg4YmRkNmU2NWVlNDVlODhlOGY1OGEzYjkzMTAxYzRhZjczNTdlNGRiOWUwOGE3NTllNiIsImlhdCI6MTY4NDMwMTIyOS42NjUzMjgsIm5iZiI6MTY4NDMwMTIyOS42NjUzMzEsImV4cCI6MTcxNTkyMzYyOS41ODMyMjQsInN1YiI6IjE2Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.p7zdlH-co2_qEQGm_8eWuV639-RicLcim0dtLvKXhWpF_dHiRO5Z3G_BAbKCqZpM%5C_-fDWuN8iZU6BFJaQWW-YK0stJsr0aNWE21vlzd2YmNvS8Q8jWC0WC5hLvYGFttWELVSJ7xc4rqRZPb4GT8Sba_xLnIi1VtKhLZtDqcbSfA_H9TvNpmRxRRDBtkIgmey7VIz9V4UedXoYBcYK0jUfi36NIIJJE_Ma5XmZftIelG2_wMhknIDm7ftFE6WXFQCsCb0lrFBrP8-7VjO5wwVf8REZZNF0IPzNaaMTlNYj3h58SJIcic6P7U06r8pNEDca1UR-zb_3hXKybn17s5OD1Fco7UDRYmy-jH6wi4sJelDK0gG7gtI5Bkz1SEcr55rAFKIu2cSrj9xEoik_5FYlNRCIeSaaDYDsD8refNoAA6m4OH_X5qm37PlAkua92jL04-T3N8ZiSKNLZjxg0eXRrEUVxTHmy7oLl68PcvaAfKdxHOKLdvtYjrcgldn250wk7AQSmLW9O-gyCACTUIr-%5C_lVNe-7maDF3L1PyWlIYHmZEgvWM5IzY0tCoo6EikVi3Nx8kd46OGSm6nofWztWAi5A-Q-7csQOyJzHN2yjd3UcLyvwyfQetZgp8yqJGqwj7H7u88rZZAnmi2LIB0ABCHuXFyVAk573SG0QiIn9FnI**

But when i change the web address to **http://localhost:5173/activate-account/3** its working fine

Here is the vue code :

```
 {
      path: '/activate-account/:token',
      name: 'activate-account',
      component: ActivateAccountView
    },
```

here is the laravel code :

```
 $mail = $user->email;
        $url = env('FRONTEND_URL') . '/activate-account/' . urlencode($token);
        Mail::send("Mail.UserActivation", ['token' => $token, 'url' => $url , 'user' => $user->name], function ($message) use ($mail) {
            $message->to($mail);
            $message->from(env('MAIL_FROM_Email'), env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'));
            $message->subject('Car Rental User Activation');
        });
```

Im new in Vue can someone tell me what i am doing wrong

I want to activate the account but its not working

Comment: there's a period in the token.  periods have special meaning in URLs which is causing the navigation to break.  you need to rethink the entire logic of sending a token in the URL and send it some other way through your app such as in a prop, saving it in local storage, or using store library like Pinia

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this same issue. Can you please check the folder structure. If you are created folder then you can add that path in URL. I hope it will work.

Comment: Hi, this is too generic. Can you explain how this may address the question?  Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encode these kind of tokens before sending it through url. Just try encoding your url like below.

```
let token = "my-Token";
let myUrl = "http://example.com/index.html?url=" + urlencode(token);
```